# Creating Boolean expressions over a set of indexed variables

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, logic

I've read lots of examples here on how to set one matrix `Equal` to another, but how do you nest `And` and `Or` around several different equalities for values a matrix of variables can take on? Using what I've found so far, I've been able to cobble something together that works, but surely someone knows a better way?

The idea: Variables `V` can take on the values in either `A` or `B` or `C`.

Minimum Working Example:

```
Apply[
  And, 
  Apply[
    Or, 
    MapThread[
       Equal,
       {Transpose[
          Table[v[i], {c, 3}, {i, 10}]], 
          Table[{-1, 0, 1}, {i, 10}]},
       2], 
    {1}]]
```

Good output:

```
(v[1] == -1 || v[1] == 0 || v[1] == 1) && (v[2] == -1 || v[2] == 0 || v[2] == 1) &&
(v[3] == -1 || v[3] == 0 || v[3] == 1) && (v[4] == -1 || v[4] == 0 || v[4] == 1) &&
(v[5] == -1 || v[5] == 0 || v[5] == 1) && (v[6] == -1 || v[6] == 0 || v[6] == 1) &&
(v[7] == -1 || v[7] == 0 || v[7] == 1) && (v[8] == -1 || v[8] == 0 || v[8] == 1) &&
(v[9] == -1 || v[9] == 0 || v[9] == 1) && (v[10] == -1 || v[10] == 0 || v[10] == 1)
```

Ideally the answer would be something of the form

```
And[Or[V == {A, B, C}]]
```

instead of the heavy use of `Table` like I have, so we can see what's happening and adapt it for other problems, and often the possible values won't have such a regular pattern as these do (A, B, & C may have irregular patterns and even repetitions in order to fill out the matrix to the right shape).

Conceivably there's a way to do something like this, but I couldn't get this to work either (for use in `Reduce` or `FindInstance`):

```
Eqns && V ∈ {-1, 0, 1}
```

Comment: Would something like `And @@ Map[Element[#, {-1, 0, 1}] &, Array[v, 10]]` work?

Comment: Alternatively, `And @@ Map[Or @@ Thread[# == {-1, 0, 1}] &, Array[v, 10]]`

Comment: Wow you're fast.  You got these comments and an answer up before I finished typing the edit at the bottom.  Your first comment looks like what I tried (and added in my edit), but I didn't think to ... um ... Map `Element` down the list. (Because Mathematica itself gives things like `{a,b} \elem Integers`.  It will take me a good long time to sort through what all your suggestions are doing.  I pick up all kinds of programming languages in a flash, but I find Mathematica incomprehensible, and the documentation paltry. I'll have to look up and remember `Array`, that's much shorter.

Comment: I like the documentation and find it useful, but it often requires going through `Basic Examples`, `Scope`, and `Properties & Relations`. I think the documentation very much has a learn-by-example style. Anyway, `Outer` is particularly useful in your case, where you have two lists, and every element in one list gets "matched" to every element in the other list somehow. `Thread` and `MapThread` or complementary, but I still sometimes have to think a moment to figure out which one to use. `Map`ping is my go-to for basically everything, so `Map`ping `Element` came naturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D array solution for multiple target arrays for OP's ideal answer (`And[Or[V == {A, B, C}]]`).

This is demonstrated with `Indexed` as it make it easier to see the effect of the solution.

First set up the 2D arrays.

```
index = Table[{r, c}, {r, 2}, {c, 2}];
\[ScriptV] = Map[Indexed[v, #] &, index, {2}];
\[ScriptA] = Map[Indexed[a, #] &, index, {2}];
\[ScriptB] = Map[Indexed[b, #] &, index, {2}];
\[ScriptC] = Map[Indexed[c, #] &, index, {2}];

MatrixForm /@ {\[ScriptV], \[ScriptA], \[ScriptB], \[ScriptC]}
```

[image]

`arrayContainsAny` builds the inequality.

```
arrayContainsAny[m_, arrayList_] :=
 And @@ Flatten@MapThread[
    Or,
    First@ListCorrelate[m, #, {1, -1}, Nothing, Equal, List] & /@ arrayList,
    3]
```

Call it with the 2D arrays.

```
eqs = arrayContainsAny[\[ScriptV], {\[ScriptA], \[ScriptB], \[ScriptC]}]
```

[image]

If values are assigned to `a`, `b`, and `c`

```
SeedRandom[123];
{a, b, c} = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 2, 2}];
```

Then `Indexed` will kick in and `eqs` will update.

[image]

However, you don't need to use `Indexed` for the `arrayList` arrays parameter. You can use the arrays directly. I just used them there to demonstrate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's just what I'm looking for, but I really have no idea what it's doing. Especially not `First` `Prefix` `ListCorrelate`.  I understand `First`, but the help file for `Prefix` is virtually nonexistent, and `ListCorrelate` just makes no sense. There is no meaning of the word kernel that makes sense here, not mathematical kernel, not software kernel, not kernel of corn, other than to think it's just the name of an argument they made up why not. I presume that if I wanted to creates something like `(v1≠a1&&v1≠a2)&&...`, I'd replace `Equal` with `NotEqual` and replace `Or` with `And`?

Comment: @TravisBemrose Yes, you can swap out `And`, `Or`, and `Equal` to make another inequality. Better yet, pass them in as parameters for additional flexibility.  For [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) have a look at the basic examples in the documentation. `Prefix` is a basically shorthand for function square-brackets (e.g. compare `Range[3]` and `Range@3`).

Answer (score 4):

Here are two options.

```
And @@ Map[Or @@ Thread[# == Range[-1, 1]] &, Array[v, 10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using `Outer`:

```
Apply[And, Or @@@ Outer[Equal, Array[v, 10], Range[-1, 1]]]
```

---

Also of possible interest, in the situation where you are using `Solve`, `Reduce` and friends:

```
And @@ Map[-1 <= # <= 1 && # ∈ Integers &, Array[v, 10]]
```

Alternatively, since `Solve`, `Reduce` and friends take a domain restriction as an optional third argument, leave out the `Integers`:

```
conds = And @@ Map[-1 <= # <= 1 &, Array[v, 10]]
```

and do something like

```
Solve[eqn && conds, Array[v, 10], Integers]
```

Comment: I get this error `FindInstance::elemc: "Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition v[1]\[Element]{-1,0,1}."` when trying `And @@ Map[# ∈ {-1, 0, 1} &, Array[v, 10]]` inside `FindInstance`.  I made sure to replace the `∈` character in case there was a copy issue. I'm sure if there's a productive way to get results down this route, but nested `And` / `Or` are working.

Comment: The thing I always forget about `Element` is that you can't use it with `List`s. `Region`s and `Domain`s have their own separate implementation (for example, `1 \[Element] {1, 2, 3}` doesn't resolve but `1 \[Element] Integers` evaluates to `True`). Therefore, I recommend using the original formulation.

Comment: I have posted an alternative.